# http header request times out on server

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers, http-request

I am trying to use a sms gateway app for android called SMSGateway with a http header request using curl as below;

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"http://182:70.76.188:9090/sendsms?phone=$phone&text=$message1&password=xxxxxxxx");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10000);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,50000);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0');
        $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        if($query){echo "Message Sent to $phone !<br>";}else{echo "Message Not Sent to $phone !<br>";echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl_handle)."<br>";}
        curl_close($curl_handle);
```

This works perfectly fine on my local system but it gets timed out when executing from server...

I need to know what is wrong...is it a curl issue ? should i use file_get_contents ? Actually I did try file_get_contents...did not work too..

Comment: You seems like giving an IPAddress which is not accessible by server? It keeps on trying to connect but not able to reach it.

Comment: But it works when run from my local system

Comment: It works in local since your local system is able to reach ur ip address but server cannot locate the ip since it is a remote server.

Comment: why ..and .. what is the solution...?

Comment: Hi All, I am deperate for an answer...please help !

Comment: have you tried   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);

Comment: Yes, I did Vishal. Doesnt work. I am using public ip of my galaxy samsung phone in which i have installed SMS gateway app. Which is set to listen to port 9090. Works when I use 192.168.1.4:9090 from my local machine. But not on the remote server. Somebody told me to use the public ip...which i am now using...still no use..

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have got the best possible answer from somebody who says

"
Ok, when connecting to your public IP from remote you're connnecting to the router, what you have to do is to redirect the connection from the router to the internal server IP, this is defined as network address translation (NAT).

In practice in your router there should be an interface in which you can define the internal IP and the port, so that the request comining from remote acts like this:

```
REMOTE_REQUEST ===> [ROUTER]PUBLIC_IP:PORT ===> [SMS SERVER]INTERNAL_IP:PORT
```

Another solution is to set the SMS server in the DMZ and expose it directly to the internet:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29
```

Check the documentation of your router, if you need help let us know the model and version.
"

The entire thread is here https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/495303/http-header-request-does-not-connect-from-remote-server